# Can we use an external Elasticsearch instance instead of inbuilt one in Sonarqube?

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

As we have maintained explicitly an Elasticsearch service on our server, can we use that Elasticsearch service instead of inbuilt one which is in Sonarqube 4.5?

If not, then can we access built in Elasticsearch service on HTTP? If so, could you please tell us how to access it?

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube embeds an E/S server for its own needs, and this should remain a black box for SonarQube users.

In SonarQube 5.0, you will be able to enable ElasticSearch HTTP connector for debugging purposes - see [SONAR-5692](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5692). But keep in mind that in no case, you should try to trick or modify the E/S servers launched by SonarQube.

Comment: You can hack as much as you want. Change the address if you will, modify the source if you so please etc. And tricking is what we do.

Comment: @ bellingard, if I wanted to use external elasticsearch with SOnarqube 6.7,is it configurable?

Comment: @AshutoshBharti SonarQube is meant to work with its own elasticsearch instance. As you can read in the previous comment, you might be able to use an external one but we don't support nor recommend this because this can have unexpected issues on your SonarQube instance.