# SonarQube: Change the elastic search client host

Tags: sonarqube, openshift, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5, openshift-cartridge

*In brief*: Is there a way of changing the target address within the elastic search *client* used by SonarQube?

*More Info*: I'd love to use SonarQube > 4.1 on OpenShift. Unfortunately, you can't bind to localhost in that environment. So [these guys](https://github.com/worldline/openshift-sonarqube/) changed the [service wrapper to piped mode](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-backend-type.html) and used the `sonar.web.host` property to set up SonarQube 4.0. Starting with [SonarQube 4.1](http://www.sonarqube.org/whats-coming-up-for-sonarqube-in-2014/) we'll also have the elastic search server that tries to bind to localhost, which leads to a crash at startup. But there's no such thing as a `sonar.search.host` property (similar to `sonar.search.port`), is there?

As a workaround, changing the binding of the server can be changed using the `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts` and [`es.network.host`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#styles) parameters.
Yeah I know, [I shouldn't be doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26528404/1845976). Because now the app crashes with a [`NoNodeAvailableException`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/NoNodeAvailableException.java)`: No node available`. That's why I'm looking for a way to change this.
Looking at [SonarQubes source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/search/SearchClient.java#L96), I presume that the client's target address is hard-coded. (I might have gotten that wrong, though)

I presume without a solution for this, we'll never SonarQube 5.0 running on OpenShift or any other environment with strict security policy.

Can anyone think of another workaround?
Maybe changing Java's definition for "localhost"/loopback interface? However, changing `/etc/hosts` doesn't work without root access. Any other ideas?

**Edit**: If you want to have a look yourself [here's how far I got so far](https://github.com/schnatterer/openshift-sonarqube). The [build file](https://github.com/schnatterer/openshift-sonarqube/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/build) is the essential part.

Comment: This limitation of openshift impacts many applications, for example postgres. As said in http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1241903739.14805210.1390938412164.JavaMail.root@redhat.com and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1024676, I don't expect SonarQube to be fixed. IMO it's up to RedHat guys to support network namespace and drop this limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible since [SonarQube 5.2, using the `sonar.search.host` property](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/0a918117ab3f9f16b92d212ef87ed46ace905485/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties#L223-L224).
For an example on how to deploy this on OpenShift, see [here](https://github.com/schnatterer/openshift-sonarqube).

Answer (score 0):

In Sonar 5.2 will be possible to set these properties, see [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/3b75c616894d079d86b2f218315da33a4636382d/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/search/SearchClient.java) . I have tried and it works (I changed this class in Sonar 5.1 source to allow configure these ES properties, see [here](http://sonar5-semanticminer.rhcloud.com/)).

Comment: Thanks for the response but it was actually myself, who submitted the [pull request](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/pull/124) for this feature :-) Let's wait until [SonarQube 5.2 is out](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR/fixforversion/20931)

Comment: I had not seen that, sorry. And thank you :), I had been struggling a long time to be able to run the Sonar 5 on OpenShift