# Configuration of management-agent on SonarQube 5.5

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-5.5, sonarqube5.6

*In brief*: Is there a way of configuring *all* Ports used by `management-agent.jar` (introduced in SonarQube 5.5) or even disabling it?

*More Info*: I'm trying to run SonarQube on OpenShift ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28594063/1845976)), this time version 5.5/5.6.
On startup I get the following error: `Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0; nested exception is: java.net.BindException: Permission denied`.

What I found out so far is that

- [the agent opens three ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552812/1845976),
- where two can be configured (System properties `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` and `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port`)
- but one of them is [by design always the ephemeral port (port 0)](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8035404), which doesn't seem to work on OpenShift.

In addition to setting the ports explicitly to the allowed range on OpenShift (ports 15000-35530), I tried the `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism` option with no luck.

Any ideas how to work around that? Can SonarQube work without the agent?

How to reproduce: 
Create an OpenShift app from [this](https://github.com/schnatterer/openshift-sonarqube), then change the `SONAR_VERSION` to `5.5` or `5.6` in `.openshift/action_hooks/build`

Full Stacktrace

```
2016.06.02 16:09:34 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -javaagent:jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Permission denied
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:384)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown by the agent 
    at sun.management.Agent.error(Agent.java:520)
    at sun.management.Agent.error(Agent.java:511)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:268)
    at sun.management.Agent.agentmain(Agent.java:134)
    at sun.management.Agent.premain(Agent.java:116)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this feedback is given just after the release of version 5.6 LTS ! There are no workarounds. Problem is referenced at  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7730.